# Change the color of part of the signal MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a simple plot as below

[image]

I would like to select the signal between 50 to 100 and change the color to red. Here is the code that I wrote

```
close all
clear all
clc

%%

t=1:200 ;
 y=sin(t);

 figure (1), hold on, plot(t, y); 
 [x1,y1] = ginput(2)


figure(2), hold on, plot(t,y,'b'), plot(t(t>=x1(1)), y(t(t>=x1(1))), 
'r',t(t<=x1(2)), y(t(t<=x1(2))),'b')
```

but what I receive is logically not correct

[image]

I wanted to change the color of samples between 50 to 100 into red. Could you please let me know how I can do it? (I examined

`t(x1(1)<t<x1(2))` but it did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that `y(t(t>=x1(1))` happens to be valid in this case because `t=1:200` corresponds to the indices of `y`.

To solve your problem you just need to find the proper values using logical indexing.

```
t=1:200;
y=sin(t);

figure (1), hold on, plot(t, y); 
[x1,y1] = ginput(2);

dt = t(2)-t(1);
figure(2), hold on;
rng1 = t < x1(1);
rng2 = (t+dt) >= x1(1) & (t-dt) <= x1(2);
rng3 = t > x1(2);
plot(t(rng1), y(rng1), 'b');
plot(t(rng2), y(rng2), 'r');
plot(t(rng3), y(rng3), 'b');
```

**Edit** I realized I potentially left gaps in the plot. Extended the inequalities to correct this.